# Plotly Adding text to upper left of each subplot…(python)

Tags: python, plotly

I have a financial chart which has a bunch of indicators as subplots. The main plot along w/ the subplot can have multiple time series displayed. I would like to display in each of those subplots the last values of any series that are plotted on that subplot, in the upper left, Similar to this:

[image]

Surprisingly, this is proving to be rather difficult. While i can find documentation to display annotations on the points/bars, and while i can display an annotation/text at the very top left of the figure, there doesn’t seem to be an easy or intuitive way to simply display some text that is not tied to the x or y axis…in my case, in the upper left.

What i have done instead is basically use the title and try to shift it to the upper left of each subplot.  Basically i start by creating a dummy title for each of the subplots in my chart. Then later on in a foreach loop when im iterating over my list of pane objects, which are basically metadata to tell me how to draw a subplot,  i at that time set the real value of the title and try to reposition to the left:

```
    row_heights, titles =  zip(*[[x.rel_height, 'title'] for x in panes if x.rel_height is not None])

    self.fig = make_subplots(rows=len(self.panes), cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, 
            vertical_spacing=0.01, row_heights=row_heights, subplot_titles=titles)

    for i, p in enumerate(self.panes):
       ...
       self.fig.layout.annotations[i].update(text = p.info, x=0.025)
       *#self.fig.layout.annotations[i].update(text = p.info, x=0.025, y=1.0)*
       ...
```

The above line will shift the title to the left nicely.  but the problem is, if i try to add a y value, that y value is based on the entire figure, not relative to the subplot..and so all the text ends up at the in one location.  The other thing is, i don't know the actual height of each subplot to know what the 'top' might be.

Any help in trying to solve this problem would be appreciated

Comment: Could you please provide a full reproducible example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotating subplots is done in the same way as make_subpllots, specifying the rows and columns. I drew the moving average, price, and volume based on the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/time-series/#time-series-using-axes-of-type-date) in the formula. The annotations can be obtained from the data frame, but I created the data separately. I used 'domain' as the coordinates for each single graph to determine the position of each graph.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')
last_volume = df["AAPL.Volume"][-1:]
last_price = ['{}:{:.2f}'.format(x, y) for x,y in zip(df.columns[1:5], df.iloc[-1, 1:5])]
last_price = ''.join(last_price)

fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1, row_heights=[0.2, 0.6, 0.20], shared_xaxes=True, vertical_spacing=0.02)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['Date'], y=df['mavg'], name='mavg'), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['Date'], y=df['dn'], name='dn'), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['Date'], y=df['up'], name='up'), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['Date'], y=df['AAPL.High'], name='AAPL.High'), row=2, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df['Date'], y=df['AAPL.Volume'], name='AAPL.Volume'), row=3, col=1)

fig.update_layout(legend=dict(
    orientation="h",
    yanchor="bottom",
    y=1.02,
    xanchor="right",
    x=1
))

fig.update_yaxes(side='right')
fig.add_annotation(xref='x domain',
                   yref='y domain',
                   x=0.01,
                   y=0.9,
                   text='Volume:' + str(last_volume.values), 
                   showarrow=False,
                   row=3, col=1)

fig.add_annotation(xref='x domain',
                   yref='y domain',
                   x=0.01,
                   y=0.99,
                   text='Price:' + str(last_price), 
                   showarrow=False,
                   row=2, col=1)


fig.update_layout(title_text='<b>AAPL Stock Cart</b>')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: this is great..i had come up with something close to, but was missing the right combination xref, yref and id not use the row, col values.   Question:   i know i can add l/r/t/b margin and pad, but can i do just a top padding for each subplot?

Comment: If you use the graph spacing, for example, row_heights=[0.15,0.6,0.15], you will get the spacing. You can also increase the spacing by setting vertical_spacing=0.6. I think you can also set the gap in the top graph with t.

Comment: thx.  row_heights will control the height of each 'pane'. vertical spacing controles the space between the pane.  what im trying to do is create an area at the top of each pane, where the description/text can be written and where the lines wont plot over.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the row height and horizontal spacing? in the three graphs, [0.15,0.6,0.15] means 15%, 60%, 15%, and the 5% that is less than 100 is applied to the spaces. The 5% that is less than 100 is applied to the blank. I think you can intend to annotate there.